# how to escape part of json loaded as object

Tags: java, json, api, testing, rest-assured

I'm not fluent in API testing hence my question. I have a body to POST (mock) that will consist of:

```
{
 "request":
 {
 "urlPath": "path/to/",
 "method": "POST",
 "bodyPatterns":[{
            "equalToJson" : "{\n\"query\": [\n{\n\"name\": \"name1\",\n\"value\": \"123\"\n        },\n{\n\"name\": \"name2\",\n\"value\": \"345\"\n},\n{\n\"name\": \"name3\",\n\"value\": \"someName\"\n}\n],\n\"anotherItem\": [],\n\"side\": 77,\n\"pageSize\": 44\n}", "jsonCompareMode": "LENIENT"
}]
 },
 "response":
 {
 "status": 200,
 "headers":
 {
 "Content-Type" : "application/json"
 },
 "body":  "{"items\": [\n{\n\"item\": 1,\n    
              \"item2\": 2,\n
              etc
"\n}\n]\n}"
 }
}
```

I want to use some pojo classes to separately create Request and Response:

```
public Request initRequest() {
        BodyPattern bodyPat = new BodyPattern();
        Query query = new Query();
        Query query2 = new Query();
        Query query3 = new Query();
        EqualToJson equalToJ = new EqualToJson();
        query.setName("name1");
        query.setValue("123");
        query2.setName("name2");
        query2.setValue("345");
        query3.setName("name2");
        query3.setValue("someName");
        List<Query> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryList.add(query);
        queryList.add(query2);
        queryList.add(query3);
        equalToJ.setQuery(queryList);
        List<Filter> filtersList = new ArrayList<>();
        equalToJ.setFilter(filtersList);
        equalToJ.setSide(77);
        equalToJ.setPageSize(44);
        List<EqualToJson> eqList = new ArrayList<>();
        eqList.add(equalToJ);

        req.setUrlPath(URL + "/Test001"); 
        req.setMethod("POST");

        bodyPat.setEqualToJson(eqList);
        bodyPat.setJsonCompareMode("LENIENT");
        List<BodyPattern> bodyPatList = new ArrayList<>();
        bodyPatList.add(bodyPat);

        req.setBodyPatterns(bodyPatList);
        return req;
}
```

To see it in more user-friendly view, here you go:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/path/to",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "equalToJson": {
          "query": [
            {
              "name": "name1",
              "value": "123"
            },
            {
              "name": "name2",
              "value": "345"
            },
            {
              "name": "name3",
              "value": "someName"
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
          ],
          "side": 77,
          "pageSize": 44
        },
        "jsonCompareMode": "LENIENT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
      "side": 77,
      "pageSize": 44,
      "items": [
        {
          "name1": "123",
          "name2": "345",
          "name3": "someName"
    etc...

        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, I do with Response.
My question is, how can I make to have just  a part of this json (BodyPatters) as escaped signs? Mock is created this way that it only accepts escaped characters in this part of json.
I can of course hardcode this payload, but I want to have control over those fields' values and steer them, as parameters.
I really have no idea how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `objectmapper` of jackson to convert Object to String. For example:

```
void name2() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Query query = new Query("name1", "123");

    EqualToJson equalToJson = new EqualToJson();
    equalToJson.setQuery(Arrays.asList(query));

    BodyPattern bodyPattern = new BodyPattern();
    bodyPattern.setEqualToJson(mapper.writeValueAsString(equalToJson));

    String bodyPatternText = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .writeValueAsString(bodyPattern);
    System.out.println(bodyPatternText);
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Query{
    private String name;
    private String value;
}

@Data
static class EqualToJson {
    private List<Query> query;
}

@Data
static class BodyPattern  {
    private String equalToJson;
}
```

This is a result:

```
{
  "equalToJson" : "{\"query\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"value\":\"123\"}]}"
}
```

Comment: ok, but how to inject it in the middle of json (object) that is being loaded do POST?

Comment: I think my example is quite straightforward. In class **BodyPattern**, instead of `private EqualToJson equalToJson`, I use `private String equalToJson`.

Comment: of course, I havent noticed. Thank you! you helped me a lot :)

Comment: if my answer is correct, can you accept and upvote it.

Comment: I did accept it, but cannot upvote because I have too low reputation score